# Как добавить дату в SQL запрос?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне в программу вставить с 1 июня 2017 года? Вот текст задания:

> Напишите запрос, возвращающий список названий аэропортов, в которых было принято более 1000 рейсов с 1 июня 2017 года.

До этого момента получилась такая программа, хоть и рейсов более 1000 не находит почему-то
[image: программа без даты]

---

Программа :

```
SELECT count(distinct flights.flight_id),airports_data.airport_name 
from flights natural join airports_data 
group by airports_data.airport_name 
order by count desc;
```

Структура базы данных :
В учебной базе данных «Авиаперевозки» имеется материализованное представление — «Маршруты» (routes)
[image: структура базы данных]

Comment: *как мне в программу вставить с 1 июня 2017 года?* Добавить соответствующий WHERE clause.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, здравствуйте, добавила.

Comment: на вашей схеме данных почему то нет таблицы routes, вместе с тем у вас какое то бессмысленное условие джойна этой таблицы указано

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct A.AIRPORT_NAME
from AIRPORTS A, BOOKINGS B, FLIGHTS F,TICKETS T, TICKET_FLIGHTS TF
where A.AIRPORT_CODE = F.ARRIVAL_AIRPORT
    and F.FLIGHT_ID = TF.FLIGHT_ID
    and T.TICKET_NO = TF.TICKET_NO
    and B.BOOK_REF = T.BOOK_REF
    and B.BOOK_DATE >= cast('01.06.2017' as date)
    and F.STATUS = 'Arrived'
```

Может так?